# Can't get data from Electron app (after deploying)

Tags: node.js, npm, build, sqlite, electron

I have an issue, I have created an elctron app and connected it to an sqlite3 database, created some crud operation and everything works perfectly fine as far as I am on developing mode (accesing from npm).BUT after packaging and building it, making as an exe file, I cant retrieve those same data that worked in dev mode.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention that much about the operations, here are two general tips just to give a few ideas:

- Check if you have any relative file references (especially if your database is located locally), try changing them to absolute references.
- Check if your executable has enough privileges to access certain services.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this link for future queries of others.
Should solve node-adodb connection problems in Electron after deploying.
Worked for me:
https://github.com/RoelVB/node-adodb/commit/be1e0c898b6a0e0c3528fa3df09b3340bd2f3795